# TABLESORTER - How do I make the first column static/fixed in TABLESORTER?

Tags: html, tablesorter

I would like to number each row and NOT have those numbers move/sort.  The first column # needs to be static/fixed.  All other columns may sort as necessary.

Is this possible?

Here is my thead:

```
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>#</th>
                    <th>Part No.</th>
                    <th>Board</th>
                    <th>Status</th>
                    <th>Auth QTY</th>
                    <th>Cur QTY</th>
                    <th>RELS</th>
                    <th>WIP QTY</th>
                    <th>TBD</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the best way would be to write your own widget ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/Zu46Z/1/)):

```
// add custom numbering widget
$.tablesorter.addWidget({
    id: "numbering",
    format: function(table) {
        var c = table.config;
        $("tr:visible", table.tBodies[0]).each(function(i) {
            $(this).find('td').eq(0).text(i + 1);
        });
    }
});

$("table").tablesorter({
    // prevent first column from being sortable
    headers: {
        0: { sorter: false }
    },
    // apply custom widget
    widgets: ['numbering']
});
```

Note: I've forked a copy of the tablesorter plugin on [github](http://mottie.github.com/tablesorter/docs/index.html) with an alphanumeric sort, more example pages and previously undocumented options. Just in case you were interested :)

Answer (score 3):

You could use CSS for this, though that's dependent on the users having an up-to-date browser, and is, while I can't test it off-hand, *probably* unsupported in IE:

```
table {
    counter-reset: rowNum;
}

tbody tr {
    position: relative;
    counter-increment: rowNum;
}

thead tr:before {
    content: ''; /* important, otherwise the columns don't line up properly */
}

tbody tr:before {
    content: counter(rowNum);
    left: -2em;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/VPymy/1/).

I left the current numbering in place, to compare the approaches. In practice this should (probably) be removed, if you choose to apply this solution.

Answer (score 0):

you could have two tables displayed inline or floated left

http://jsfiddle.net/AfmPz/

```css
td, th
{
  padding:3px;
}
table
{
  float:left;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>#</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Part No.</th>
      <th>Board</th>
      <th>Status</th>
      <th>Auth QTY</th>
      <th>Cur QTY</th>
      <th>RELS</th>
      <th>WIP QTY</th>
      <th>TBD</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>na</td>
      <td>na</td>
      <td>na</td>
      <td>na</td>
      <td>na</td>
      <td>na</td>
      <td>na</td>
      <td>na</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>na</td>
      <td>na</td>
      <td>na</td>
      <td>na</td>
      <td>na</td>
      <td>na</td>
      <td>na</td>
      <td>na</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>na</td>
      <td>na</td>
      <td>na</td>
      <td>na</td>
      <td>na</td>
      <td>na</td>
      <td>na</td>
      <td>na</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```